# LMDB Library cannot be loaded by `LibraryLoad`, how to compile properly

Tags: warning-messages, librarylink, function-compile, compiler

I cloned LMDB* from https://github.com/LMDB/lmdb and compiled on a Mac M1 with

```
make -e clean liblmdb.so CC="cc -target aarch64-macos-none"
```

which produced the .so.  Other targets may be found [here](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/blob/master/cross-compile.sh).  I can see the functions in the .so with `nm -D`.

In a Mathematica notebook, I tried

```
LibraryLoad["/path/to/liblmdb.so"]
```

which results in the error

> [image: LibraryLoad failure]

When trying to load a specific function, the message ends with

> "liblmdb.so is not a structured library that can be loaded."

## Questions

- Is this because Mathematica can only load specially compiled libraries, i.e. include wolfram headers?  I'm confused since the doc says

> "Libraries loaded using LibraryLoad do not need to follow the Wolfram Library Link specification"

- Does the [Foreign Function Interface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ForeignFunctionInterface.html) make this possible/simpler?  I'm on 12, but maybe this is the final selling point for 13.
- Is there a simple way to guide the compilation with Mathematica that I'm overlooking?

* "Lighweight Memory-Mapped Database"

Comment: I don't have knowledge of the Apple ecosystem, and I could be wrong but have you tried other architecture, Mathematica finished the transition to Apple Silicon in 12.3.1 (maybe changing target works). Besides that writing interface for Mathematica takes time, wouldn't be better to use the already written interface like [Python](https://github.com/jnwatson/py-lmdb), or [Julia](https://github.com/wildart/LMDB.jl) or even better [Java](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava) and call them from Mathematica?

Comment: I can load the compiled library in _Mathematica_ 13.3 on Fedora Linux.

Comment: @Ben Izd why do you say Java > Julia?  Faster?  "Lower level" in some sense (what sense)?

Answer (score 2):

I've mentioned Java because Wolfram Language can run Java code directly without using `ExternalEvaluate` or similar functions. To illustrate my point, I've translated the `tutorial1` from [lmdbjava's TutorialTest](https://github.com/lmdbjava/lmdbjava/blob/master/src/test/java/org/lmdbjava/TutorialTest.java).

As noted by the developer, we should run the code with some parameters, run the following code first (I'm on Windows):

```
Needs["JLink`"];

ReinstallJava[
 CommandLine -> 
  "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-19\\bin\\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED"]
```

Then download the required Jar files. Fortunately `lmdbjava` embed the Windows, Linux or OS X machine for 64-bit platforms, no need to add `lmdb`. If you store the files (for version 0.8.3, it consists of 12 jar files) in a path, add it to the Java classpath, like below:

```
AddToClassPath[path];
```

Load the libraries:

```
LoadJavaClass /@ {"org.lmdbjava.Dbi", "org.lmdbjava.Env", 
   "org.lmdbjava.Txn", "java.nio.ByteBuffer", 
   "java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets", "org.lmdbjava.DbiFlags", 
   "java.io.File", "java.io.IOException", "org.lmdbjava.EnvFlags"};
```

Now the translated `tutorial1` (with slight modification, I didn't delete the key):

```
JavaBlock[
  Module[{path, env, dbName = "my DB", db, key, value, txn, found, 
    fetchedVal, openDBflagsTemp},

   path = JavaNew["java.io.File", "C:\\temp"];
   
   env = (((Env`create[])@setMapSize[10485760])@setMaxDbs[1])@
     open[path, JavaNew["[Lorg.lmdbjava.EnvFlags;", 0]];
   openDBflagsTemp = MakeJavaObject[{DbiFlags`MDBUCREATE}];
   
   db = env@openDbi[dbName, openDBflagsTemp];

   key = ByteBuffer`allocateDirect[env@getMaxKeySize[]];
   value = ByteBuffer`allocateDirect[700];

   key@put[
      JavaNew["java.lang.String", "greeting"]@
       getBytes[StandardCharsets`UTFU8]]@flip[];
   value@
    put[JavaNew["java.lang.String", "Hello world"]@
       getBytes[StandardCharsets`UTFU8]]@flip[];

   db@put[key, value];

   txn = env@txnRead[];

   found = db@get[txn, key];
   fetchedVal = txn@val[];

   Print[
    "Found: \"" <> 
     StandardCharsets`UTFU8@decode[fetchedVal]@toString[] <> "\""];

   txn@close[];
   env@close[];
   ]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Outputs:

```
Found: "Hello world"

{0.0918759, Null}
```

For reading, I used the following code:

```
JavaBlock[
  Module[{path, env, dbName = "my DB", db, key, txn, found, 
    fetchedVal},

   path = JavaNew["java.io.File", "C:\\temp"];

   env = Env`open[path, 10, JavaNew["[Lorg.lmdbjava.EnvFlags;", 0]];
   db = env@openDbi[dbName, JavaNew["[Lorg.lmdbjava.DbiFlags;", 0]];

   key = ByteBuffer`allocateDirect[env@getMaxKeySize[]];

   key@put[
      JavaNew["java.lang.String", "greeting"]@
       getBytes[StandardCharsets`UTFU8]]@flip[];

   txn = env@txnRead[];

   found = db@get[txn, key];
   fetchedVal = txn@val[];

   Print[
    "Found: \"" <> 
     StandardCharsets`UTFU8@decode[fetchedVal]@toString[] <> "\""];

   txn@close[];
   env@close[];
   ]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Output:

```
Found: "Hello world"

{0.0060942, Null}
```

Whether `0.0918759`, or `0.0060942` are fast enough depends on your workload. The point here is I manage to used the library inside Wolfram Language without any prior experience with it pretty fast.
You can do a similar thing with `Python` and `Julia` using [`ExternalFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalFunction.html).

If you developed an interface for this library, make sure you published it here for future readers.

Versions:

```
13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)
JDK-19
lmdbjava-0.8.3
```